# Having issues resizing divs when the browser window is resized

Tags: html, resize, position, window

I have 3 divs. each one is below the other. each one 'should' resize when the browser window is resized, however only the last one is resizing correctly.

```css
div#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: pink;
  font-family: arial;
}

div#block-wrapper {
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

div.heading {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px 0px 50px 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

div.heading h4 {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
}

div.content {
  margin: 150px auto;
}

div.bar {
  margin: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="block-wrapper">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="heading">
        <h4>Level 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-wrapper">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="heading">
        <h4>Level 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="block-wrapper">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="heading">
        <h4>Level 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they are all resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the position:absolute to position:relative and making each group a float:left